# Using an ARIMA model to output many different scenarios of future wind generation

Tags: forecasting, arima, modeling, moving-average, volatility

I am looking to model potential scenarios of wind generation for next year (specifically August). I have read through the literature and decided on using an ARIMA model. I have 10 different data sets for August from 2013-2021 or so.

So my question is, I use my historical data to create a projection, but I would like to run a model that outputs say 1,000 different scenarios. I don't see an initial random seed as a possibility although that is my probably just my ignorance.

The end result of this data is to figure out wind generation in all scenarios and push it into a model that determines what range of electricity prices (based on this output of wind generation) would make it worthwhile to purchase said wind contract.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARIMA makes assumptions about the distribution of the innovations - specifically, it assumes they are normally distributed with mean zero. In the course of fitting an ARIMA model, the variance of this distribution is estimated. Thus, a fitted ARIMA model will not only give you a point forecast, but a full *predictive density*.

So my recommendation would be to sample from this predictive density. In R:

```
library(forecast)
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
plot(forecast(model,h=12))
replicate(10,simulate(model,n=1))
# 451.8679 468.8403 452.7626 452.3362 429.0245 452.2179 439.9903 436.7220 438.8253 437.2215
```

[image: ARIMA forecast]

In your particular case, you note you have ten different time series. You can fit an ARIMA model to each of them, and sample 100 future realizations from each, for 1,000 samples altogether. (Whether this makes sense depends on how your ten original time series hang together.)

Note that each sample will of course come from the same fitted ARIMA model. But ARIMA models come with model uncertainty (pertaining to the model form, i.e., the AR, MA and integration orders), as well as parameter uncertainty (pertaining to the values of the parameter estimates). If you want to capture these, you could slightly perturb your original time series, then fit a model, then sample just once from this model. Do this entire process 100 times for each time series, and you will get a far wider range of simulations, which will likely be more realistic. Of course, fitting 100 times as many models will also take much more time.

Comment: I can't upvote anything yet, but thank you so much for your time Stephan. I have spent so many hours looking for some direction and this was precisely what I was after.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Good luck!